# How do I execute transitions in AASM from controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1, aasm

Is it possible to safely execute transition in AASM using its name?

What I'm doing now in AASM:

```
if order.aasm.events.include? params[:event]
  order.send(params[:event]) 
  order.save
end
```

What I could do in `state_machine`

```
order.state_event = params[:event]
order.save
```

Comment: I needed this in my project too and have created a concern to do this: https://gist.github.com/spieker/a01966e2dd586b47b04f

Answer (score 1):

Can you include your `aasm do` block?  I haven't used `state_machine` before, but this isn't how one typicaly uses `aasm`. You shouldn't need to ever send a transition; rather you just call the event and your transition of states occurs automatically based on the event/transition rules you have created.

Here is a small example.

```
aasm do
  state :draft
  state :review
  state :accepted
  state :rejected

  event :submit do
    transitions :from => :draft, :to => :review
    transitions :from => :review, :to => :accepted
  end

  event :reject do
    transitions :form => :review, :to => :rejected
  end
end
```

Now in the example above, if the object is in the draft state and you call `object.submit` it will transition from `draft to review` and if you are in the review state `object.submit` will transition from `review to accepted`.

Also note, instead of calling the event and then calling save you can append an `!` to the event name and the save will occur automatically after the transition completes.

So instead of

```
object.submit
object.save
```

You can simply call

```
object.submit!
```

Comment: When I said transition, I actually meant event. I'm trying to make the object state controllable through API. Should I execute events using `object.send("#{params[:event]}!")` or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: In that case you can use `send` on the object in the way you have described. I would recommend setting your aasm do block like this `aasm :whiny_transitions => false do` this will simply return true or false instead of raising an exception if the event isn't currently valid. It eliminates the need for your include check.